# Avro Schema - what is "avro.java.string": "String"

Tags: avro

I've got my Kafka Streams processing configuration for `AUTO_REGISTER_SCHEMAS` set to true.

I noticed in this auto generated schema it creates the following 2 types

```
{
      "name": "id",
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "avro.java.string": "String"
      }
},
```

Could someone please explain why it creates 2 types and what exactly `"avro.java.string": "String"` is.

Thanks

Comment: There's only one type. It's a string, but it's clarified to a specific subclass

Comment: Is this going to be a problem when a Python client tries to work with this schema?

Comment: The behavior of the class generator which modifies schemas by replacing AVRO strings  with Java specific logical types is a bug:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2838 as it does indeed become a problem with interoperability with Python and other languages

Comment: Confluent has added a property that can be set on the serializer to prevent this from occurring: avro.remove.java.properties

Answer (score 13):

By default Avro uses `CharSequence` for the String representation,  the following syntax allows you to overwrite the default behavior and use java.lang.String as the String type for the instances of the fields declared like this

```
"type": {
        "type": "string",
        "avro.java.string": "String"
      }
```